# Joining values to a string - error

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have 14 dictionaries all containing the same keys of information, but varying values. I'm trying to build a function that will put together a sentence when the dictionary is listed as the argument in the function.

The error is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Here is the code:

```
def createhouses(x): 
    count = 0
    for i in [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14]:
                    i["sn"] = legendary[count]
                    i["fn"] = [legendaryfn[count]]
                    i["family"] = [hProfession[random.randint(0, len(hProfession)-1)]]
                    i["house"] = [houseGen()]
                    i["fortune"] = [prosperity[random.randint(0, len(prosperity)-1)]]
                    i["tort"] = random.randint(0, 1)
                    count+=1
createhouses(1)
```

And the code that is throwing up the error:

```
def houseHistory(x):
        print x['fn']+" "+x['sn']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createHouses`, you have put list for some of the dictionary keys, like: -

```
i["fn"] = [legendaryfn[count]]
i["house"] = [houseGen()]
```

So, you can't concatenate a `list` with a `str` object in `x['fn']+" "+x['sn']`. Since `x['fn']` gives you a `list` object.

So, change them to: -

```
i["fn"] = legendaryfn[count]
i["house"] = houseGen()
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, the majority of my errors seem to be small oversights, guess it's just a part of learning. Thank you again.